# How to submit a workflow job on a non-HA cluster in Oozie

Tags: alibaba-cloud

In E-MapReduce cluster, Oozie user are installed with sharelib by default in Alibaba Cloud ECS.

I want to submit a workflow job on a non-HA cluster. Can anyone help me to achieve this.

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 0):

Since clusters with and without enabled HA have different modes to access NameNode and ResourceManager, Please follow the below steps to submit a workflow job.

**Step1: Configure NameNode and JobTracker in `job.properties` file.**

```
nameNode=hdfs://emr-header-1:9000

jobTracker=emr-header-1:8032
```

**Step2: Submit a workflow job**

1. Log on to the main master node of the cluster.

   ```
   ssh root@publicIp_of_master
   ```
2. Download the code from OSS

   ```
   [root@emr-header-1 ~]# su oozie
   [oozie@emr-header-1 root]$ cd /tmp
   [oozie@emr-header-1 tmp]$ wget http://OSS PATH/oozie-examples.zip
   [oozie@emr-header-1 tmp]$ unzip oozie-examples.zip
   ```
3. Synchronize Oozie workflow code to hdfs.

   ```
   [oozie@emr-header-1 tmp]$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal examples/ /user/oozie/examples
   ```
4. Submit an Oozie workflow sample job.

   ```
   [oozie@emr-header-1 tmp]$ $OOZIE_HOME/bin/oozie job -config examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run
   ```

Note: After a successful execution, a jobId will be returned.